# R：how to extract the exact character between two characters for a vector

Tags: r

```
dat1 <- c('human(display_long)|uniprotkb:ESR1(gene name)')
dat2 <- c('human(display_long)|uniprotkb:TP53(gene name)')
dat3 <- c('human(display_long)|uniprotkb:GPX4(gene name)')
dat4 <- c('human(display_long)|uniprotkb:ALOX15(gene name)')
dat5 <- c('human(display_long)|uniprotkb:PGR(gene name)')
dat <- c(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5)
```

how to extract the gene name between 'human(display_long)|uniprotkb:' and '(gene name)' for vector dat.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexpr` and `regmatches` to *extract the text between `human(display_long)|uniprotkb:` and `(gene name)`*.

```
regmatches(dat
 , regexpr("(?<=human\\(display_long\\)\\|uniprotkb:).*(?=\\(gene name\\))"
 , dat, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```

Where `(?<=human\\(display_long\\)\\|uniprotkb:)` is a positive look behind for `human(display_long)|uniprotkb:` and `(?=\\(gene name\\)` is a positive look ahead for `(gene name)` and `.*` is the text in between.

Another way is to use `sub` but this might fail in case there is no match.

```
sub(".*human\\(display_long\\)\\|uniprotkb:(.*)\\(gene name\\).*", "\\1", dat)
#[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```

Other ways not searching for the full pattern might be:

```
regmatches(dat, regexpr("(?<=:)[^(]*", dat, perl=TRUE))
sub(".*:([^(]*).*", "\\1", dat)
sub(".*:(.*)\\(.*", "\\1", dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex which will extract the text between `'uniprotkb'` and opening round brackets (`(`).

```
sub('.*uniprotkb:(\\w+)\\(.*', '\\1', dat)
#[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr` and look behind you could try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(dat, "(?<=:)[A-z0-9]+")
#[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```

Assuming that there is only one colon which precedes the gene name.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(dat, ".*uniprotkb:|\\(.*")
[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```

---

Or use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(dat, whitespace = ".*uniprotkb:|\\(.*")
[1] "ESR1"   "TP53"   "GPX4"   "ALOX15" "PGR"
```